# Access the event object in a mxml property bound onEvent code

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

When binding code to the execution of an event using mxml, by assigning the Event metadata property to the code, it in the case of:

```
<s:ViewStack change="onChange()">
```

Is there a way to access the event object?

Comment: Don't forget to indent your code by 4 spaces in the editor, or it simply won't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the event like so:

```
<s:ViewStack change="onChange(event)">
```

Then write your handler:

```
private function onChange(event:IndexChangedEvent){
//do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the variable name of the event object.